# imploding array values to attributes of a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a text component with the following code

```
  return (
    <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
      <Grid container>
        <TextField
          id={props.id}
          label={props.label}
          defaultValue={props.defaultValue || ""}
          variant="outlined"
        />
      </Grid>
    </FormControl>
  );
```

the props.attributes is an array

```
props.attributes = ['required','disabled']
```

I want the attributes as the text field attributes as below

```
        <TextField
          id={props.id}
          label={props.label}
          defaultValue={props.defaultValue || ""}
          variant="outlined"
          required
          disabled
        />
```

I tried making the attribute array a string using

```
const attributes = props.attributes ? props.attributes.join(" ") : "";
```

and then inserting the string inside the textfield attributes like this

```
<TextField
          id={props.id}
          label={props.label}
          defaultValue={props.defaultValue || ""}
          variant="outlined"
         {...attributes}
        />
```

But didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attributes` should be an object so if you convert attributes to an object that should work
check below code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const attr = { disabled: true, required: false };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <input type="text" {...attr} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

working fiddle is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kn4tku?file=src%2FApp.js)

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to send props object like

```
props = { id: 'text-id', label: 'some-label', disable: true, required: false };
```

and pass this to component like

```
<TextField
    {...props}
/>
```

that's it

Answer (score 1):

Convert array into object

Replace this

```
const attributes = props.attributes ? props.attributes.join(" ") : "";
```

to

```
const attributes = props.attributes
  ? props.attributes.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (!acc[curr]) {
      acc[curr] = true
    }
    return acc;
  }, {}) : "";
```